# String from server cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, http

My server returns a JSON object via the body of an HTTP POST response, but I get the this error when my app tries to convert the string into a JSONObject:

```
06-02 09:05:34.380: E/JSONException_MyAppService(19913): org.json.JSONException: Value {"VALS":{"VAL1":"hello","VAL2":"hello2","VAL3":"hello3"}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

It looks like my server is returning a acceptable JSON encoded string, but it just won't convert to a JSONObject. I even changed the content-type of the server's response header to "application/json". Please help me fix this, I've been trying all day.

EDIT- I use the following code:

```
try {
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
    JSONObject response=new JSONObject(responseBody);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("ClientProtocol_"+TAG,""+e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("IO_"+TAG,""+e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("JSONException_"+TAG,""+e);
}
```

I also tried imran khan's suggestion:

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
        // parsing JSON
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(retSrc); //Convert String to JSON Object
        JSONArray tokenList = result.getJSONArray("VALS");

        JSONObject oj = tokenList.getJSONObject(0);
        String token = oj.getString("VAL1"); 
        String token1 = oj.getString("VAL2");
        String token11 = oj.getString("VAL3");  
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("ClientProtocol_"+TAG,""+e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("IO_"+TAG,""+e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("JSONException_"+TAG,""+e);
}
```

:'( :'(

Comment: Please provide the code where you doing the same and full log cat.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you doing it? It should work with:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject (yourString);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes that is exactly how I am doing it:

`JSONObject response=new JSONObject(responseBody);`

Comment: Can you edit your question including the code where you get the response?

Comment: I have tried to parse your response and it's working. I don't know how you are passing the string, but maybe you have to scape the quotes \"

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. It would be interesting to log the responseBody string before converting to JSONObject to see what you are getting there.

Comment: it must be something my server is doing... this time I created a JSONObject from within my code, passed it on to my server via POST, then I had the server pass the EXACT same JSONObject right back to my code, but I still get the error. :(

Comment: I think the problem is in the String. Maybe some quotes. Can you try to log in Eclipse the String you are getting as response and copy it here? I tried to create a JSONObject with your response and it works:  JSONObject object = new JSONObject ("{\"VALS\":{\"VAL1\":\"hello\",\"VAL2\":\"hello2\",\"VAL3\":\"hello3\"}}");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12065/discussion-between-miguel-rodelas-and-user1408996)

Comment: `TO EVERYBODY:` **miguel.rodelas's** theory is most likely correct. It looks like a special character escaping issue... it just can't be anything else... I tried everyone's suggestion, but the error always occurs at _new JSONObject()_. I'm going to experiment more and update this thread about my progress. Thank you all for responding, I gave you all +1s.

Comment: I fixed it see my answer below :) Your explanation came pretty close, so I accepted it. The problem was within the string itself, not the Java. The server probably used some incorrect encoding, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert string to json as:

```
      String str="{\"VALS\":{\"VAL1\":\"hello\",\"VAL2\":\"hello2\",\"VAL3\":\"hello3\"}}";
  try {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(str);
    JSONObject resultf = result.getJSONObject("VALS");
    Toast.makeText(this, resultf.getString("VAL1").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, resultf.getString("VAL2").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, resultf.getString("VAL3").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

        }
```

Comment: try my answer and if u have any problem then i will guide u thanks

Comment: I think this would fail because there isn't an array in the response (for an array [] are needed). VALS should be parsed as a JSONObject.

Comment: @miguel.rodelas :maybe you are right but u can check http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ here

Comment: I tried but it gives the exact same error message (i kept the same catch clauses from my previous code)

Comment: @user1408996: at least in Android that is a JSONObject with VAL1, VAL2 and VAL3 as String attributes, 100% sure. I have just tried it on Eclipse and with a JSONArray you get a JSONException.

Comment: @imran : I have changed your code please take look ..... as per http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT! It was entirely my server's fault. It turned out that my server was responding incorrectly. What happened was there was a bug within the web framework and after updating to the latest version, the problem solved itself. I'm guessing the old version of the web framework returned the incorrect content-type response header, or used some weird encoding.

So everyone's Java code here should be 100% correct, because Java was not at fault here. THANKS FOR ALL YOUR EFFORT!

Miguel's answer was the closest explanation, so I will accept his answer.